# C# Code Block in Spark View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, spark-view-engine

Can the Spark View Engine handle C# Code blocks like Razor can? For example, I have the following in Razor:

```
@{
   var currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string ?? "Home";
   var currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string ?? "Index";
   var currentPage = (currentController + "-" + currentAction ).ToLower();
}
```

What would the equivalent of that be in the Spark View Engine? I am then using the code like so in Razor, and I want to do same in Spark.

```
<li @(currentPage == "home-index" ? "class = current" : "")>
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `#` to indicate a line is code only, so:

```
# var currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string ?? "Home";
# var currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string ?? "Index";
# var currentPage = (currentController + "-" + currentAction ).ToLower();
```

also, if all you're doing is declaring variables, you could instead just do:

```
<var currentController="ViewContext.RouteData.Values['controller'] as string ?? 'Home'" />
```

your usage would look like:

```
<li class="current?{currentPage == "home-index"}">
    ${Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")}
</li>
```

Comment: I would also advocate putting these variables in to ViewData in a base Controller or global filter so they're available to any view.

Comment: I followed your first suggestion, but I get the error: The name 'currentController' does not exist in the current context. :( Q updated also.

Comment: hmm.. it's working just fine for me. in the error message you get, the full source for the view should be in the message. examine the source and see if you can find where the variable is being used and where it's being declared.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had missed the keyword `var` on the `currentController` :) Marked as Answer. Thank you Dave.

Comment: The # syntax is great to wrap an HTML helper (e.g. `${Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath("CustomTemplate")}`) call into a `try {...} catch(Exception e) {...}` block.